# iPhoto very slow to load photo library

Tags: macos, iphoto

iPhoto on my iMac is very slow to load because of a very large master library (about 50,000 photos).

Is there any way to split the master library into 2 or 3 parts so that only one part (with the most recent photos) opens on loading and the other parts are only loaded when needed?

My iMac is running OS X 10.6.1 and iPhoto '09 8.1.2 (424).

Answer (score 0):

Apple support has a support page on this: [Create a new iPhoto library or switch between libraries](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2505).

It is currently for iPhoto 11 but I believe the same options apply.